# con.connect is not a function: using Knex.js, express-session, pg and connect-pg-simple

Tags: node.js, postgresql, database-connection, knex.js, express-session

I am making a site with express-session, connect-pg-simple, passport.js, Knex.js, pg and PostgreSQL and am currently experiencing what appears to be an issue with my session store or database connection when I start my server.

I can start my server but I also get this message in my console:

```
Failed to prune sessions: con.connect is not a function
```

I have no idea what this means as I don't have 'con.connect' anywhere in the code that I have written. I can't find any explanation or solution for this online, but I presume that it must be related to the connection between my database and the session store.

This is what my knexfile looks like:

```
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '.env.development') });

const dbMode = 
   process.env.VITE_ENV === 'development' ? {
    client: "pg",
    connection: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5432,
      user: process.env.VITE_DB_USER,
      password: process.env.VITE_DB_PASS,
      database: process.env.VITE_DB_NAME,
      charset: 'utf8'
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: './server/db/migrations',
      tableName: "knex_migrations"
    },
    seeds: {
      directory: './server/db/seeds'
    }
  } : {
    client: "pg",
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: { require: true }
}

module.exports = dbMode;
```

Here's my session file:

```
const path = require('path');
const dbCon = require('../../knexfile');
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', '.env.development') });
const express_session = require('express-session');
const pgSession = require('connect-pg-simple')(express_session);

const theSecret = process.env.VITE_SESSION_SECRET;

const session = express_session({
    store: new pgSession({ tableName: 'sessions', conObject: dbCon }),
    secret: theSecret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 },
})

module.exports = session;
```

My db file:

```
const knex = require('knex');
const dbConfig = require('../../knexfile');
const db = knex(dbConfig);

module.exports = db;
```

And finally my initServer.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('./db/session');
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '..', '.env') });
const { passport } = require('./passport');

app.use(cors({
    origin: process.env.VITE_CORS_ORIGIN,
    credentials: true
}));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(session);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(require('./routes'));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).send("Unable to find requested resource.")
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err) {
        req.logout();
        next();
    }
    res.status(err.status || 500).send(err.message);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`)
});
```

There is no proper error message for this so I really don't know what's causing my session store or the connection to fail.

I would really appreciate your help with solving this issue, which doesn't seem to have much info online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the precise cause of the problem was, but it must have been related to some sort of interaction between Knex.js and connect-pg-simple.

By uninstalling connect-pg-simple and replacing it with an alternative suited more specifically to Knex (namely connect-session-knex) I was able to get the session store to start up without any errors.